# Intersection between two date intervals

Tags: ruby, date

i have four dates:

First two are the beginning and end of a month

```
start_m = Time.new(2010,1).beginning_of_month
end_m = Time.new(2010,1).end_of_month
```

and the last two, `d1` and `d2`, with `d1 <= d2`

What i want is an array containing the day numbers that come from the intersection of `start_m` -> `end_m` and `d1`->`d2`

for example:

```
start_m = 2011-01-01
end_m = 2011-01-31
d1 = 2010-12-20
d2 = 2011-01-11
```

the result would be

```
[1,2,3 ... 11]
```

is there an easy approach to do this intersection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'date'

start_m = Date.parse('2011-01-01')
end_m = Date.parse('2011-01-31')
d1 = Date.parse('2010-12-20')
d2 = Date.parse('2011-01-11')

puts (start_m..end_m).to_a & (d1..d2).to_a
```

---

See documentation for [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M000274.html) . Output:

```
2011-01-01
2011-01-02
2011-01-03
2011-01-04
2011-01-05
2011-01-06
2011-01-07
2011-01-08
2011-01-09
2011-01-10
2011-01-11
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use the range.step function from ruby using `(start_m.to_i..end_m.to_i).step(60*60*24).to_a`.

Then you would need to convert each element from the array using `Time.at(element).day`

Doing this for both of the arrays, you can do `array1 & array2` which will give you the results you want.

This is just a suggestion, maybe there are better ways to do this.